# How to properly use the json-2-csv node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

I'm pretty new to nodeJS so maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm trying to use the node module [json-2-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv). But when I follow the docs and try and use it I get undefined as my result.

Here's the code that I tried with the test data. Also, I already ran `npm install json-2-csv` and checked my package.json to see if its there (version 3.5.4)

```
let converter = require('json-2-csv');


var array = [
    {
        "configurationId": {
        "id": "4000",
        "displayName": "4000",
        "uri": "/configuration/users/4000"
        },
        "actualValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ],
        "inheritedValue": [],
        "effectiveValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "configurationId": {
        "id": "4001",
        "displayName": "4001",
        "uri": "/configuration/users/4001"
        },
        "actualValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ],
        "inheritedValue": [],
        "effectiveValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "configurationId": {
        "id": "4002",
        "displayName": "40002",
        "uri": "/configuration/users/4002"
        },
        "actualValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ],
        "inheritedValue": [],
        "effectiveValue": [
            {
            "id": "Agent",
            "displayName": "Agent",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
            },
            {
            "id": "SMS",
            "displayName": "SMS",
            "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
            }
        ]
    }
    ];

var result = converter.json2csv(array, function(err, csv){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
}, expandArrayObjects = true);
console.log("result is...", result);
```

The important bit probably being this line here:

```
var result = converter.json2csv(array, function(err, csv){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
}, expandArrayObjects = true);
```

This was my output:

```
Info: Start process (12:03:39 p.m.)
the result is... undefined
Error:  null
Info: End process (12:03:39 p.m.)
```

I expected the output to be csv formatted text but as you can see from above I get undefined. I think I'm using it incorrectly but don't really have experience with this stuff to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params for `.json2csv` is `(csv, function, options)`. where according to [npm source]

```
options - (Optional) A JSON document specifying any of the following key value pairs:
```

So, the code will be:

```
var result = converter.json2csv(array, function(err, csv){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    console.log("Result: ", csv);
}, {expandArrayObjects:true});
```

If you want to use other settings the `options` object will be:

```
{
    expandArrayObjects: true,
    ....
    ....
}
```

But I am not confident this will work, not because of the syntax, but because I doubt json2csv can convert deep json to CSV.

Also, `result` will not have the data as the data is passed via callback and it is an async function. You need to `console.log` it or use the variable inside the callback.

Comment: Ahh that format makes so much more sense. But trying it still returns me an undefined for result. And ya you might be right but I may as well try and hope lol,

Comment: Oh One more thing, it should be inside callback, result is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: kk that fixed and ya you were kinda right it weirdly went deep with the headers but didnt get the values of deeper objects and just nulled them. But anyways I'll accept you answer since it completely answered my question. Thank you